# Drupal - show content from a content type in different regions

Tags: drupal, content-type

I am a newbie on Drupal.

I am building a product page whose layout is 2 column, the first column (main content) displays text content and the second column (right hand side) displays two information boxes one below the other.

To implement this I created a new content type called "product detail" and added two text fields calling it as box1 and box2.

Now, when I post a page using the "product detail" content type, it shows the 2 fields below the main content.
I configured the managed fields to 'Exclude' so they are not part of $content. 
But now, I don't see them, how do I get them to show them on the RHS?

My .info file has $content and $right.

Thanks,
jackdive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with the ins- and outs of developing blocks, or assigning variables to a theme, I suggest you use the "turnkey" solution called [cck_blocks](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks).

Otherwise, the pattern you are looking for is:

- Use template preprocessors to extract certain field values of the current shown node.
- Shrub (XSS etc) and print these values anywhere in the template.

Comment: Thanks berkes. I used the cck_blocks to render the fields.